# Selenium didn't identify locator with "middle operator" in ID

Tags: selenium

I have a problem identifying a locator, the id has a "middle dot" operator ·

id=xf-98\$xforms-input-1·1

second to last character.
Please give some suggestions to resolve this.

Can we use Regular expressions in xpath?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select `div` tag with `id=xf-98\$xforms-input-1·1` , then you can use part of `id` to build your xpath as below:

```
//div[contains(@id,'xforms-input')]
```

Comment: But if we have multiple  id with text "xforms-input",again not able to locate unique element. Example: "xf-141$xf-316$$e0·2"  "xf-141$xf-316$$e0·3"   "xf-141$xf-316$$e0·4"  "xf-141$xf-316$$e0·5"